# MAUI WebView not displaying on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, maui

I have created an app that serves as a webview to my website, the `WebView` component displays properly on Android and Windows, but it doesn't display on my iOS (iphone 11) device running iOS 16.X

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MltDimParisPhoneApp.EnglishPage" 
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGrey">
        <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="8">
            <Button Text="Go Back" TextColor="DarkSlateGray"/>
            <Button Text="Select Language" x:Name="ChangeLangBtn" TextColor="DarkSlateGray"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <WebView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                     Source="https://example.com" 
                     VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                     x:Name="WebView"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The `WebView` doesn't display, but the other controls do.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the webview code as follows:

```
<WebView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                     Source="https://example.com" 
                     MinimumHeightRequest="1000"
                     MinimumWidthRequest="200" 
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     x:Name="WebView"/>
```

Comment: it is a valid solution, but it forces a fixed height, instead, I changed the layout from StackLayout to Grid at the root level, it fixed my issues

Comment: Care to share some code? :)